# how to call split method on designtime binding value

Tags: asp.net

Hi all
I have a grid with some templatecolumn , now i want to bind to on object property.
one of these property is a string type that i want split it in design time.
my code is here, but i have error. i know my code is wrong. please help me if any one know the right option to do this.

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="FilePath" UniqueName="FilePath" HeaderText="نام فایل" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FilePath.Split('-').Last();")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast our `Eval`'s expression to a type of `string` and then call `Split` method:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# ((string)Eval(FilePath)).Split('-').Last() %>
</ItemTemplate>
```